# Using \startcombination with \starttyping

Tags: context, verbatim, sidebyside

How do I put two blocks of verbatim text side by side? Using `\starttyping` within `\startcombination` runs the lines together instead of having a break between them.

MWE:

```
\starttext 
\startcombination[2*1]
{
\starttyping
This is sample line 1
This is sample line 2
This is sample line 3
\stoptyping
} { A }
{
\starttyping
Alternative line 1
Alternative line 2
Alternative line 3
\stoptyping
} { B }
\stopcombination 
\stoptext
```

I've tried `\placesidebyside` as will, with similar results.

Answer (score 6):

The main use of combinations is to arrange multiple images in a single block, as a result ConTeXt uses a horizontal box to store the image. When you want to place text with multiple lines in a combination you have to put it a a vertical box which allows line breaks.

While you can use the normal `\framed` (or its `\startframed` alternative) command the `framedtext` environment is better suited because it has better spacing at the top and bottom of the enclosed text.

To get the proper width of the box you have to add `location=none` to `framedtext` because otherwise it will take up the whole width of the text block. With `strip=yes` for the `typing` environment you ensure the leading space at the begin of the lines is removed from th output.

```
\starttext 

\startcombination[2*1]
    \startcontent
        \startframedtext[location=none,frame=off,offset=0pt,width=fit] % width=.45\textwidth
            \starttyping[strip=yes]
            This is sample line 1
            This is sample line 2
            This is sample line 3
            \stoptyping
        \stopframedtext
    \stopcontent
    \startcaption
        A
    \stopcaption
    \startcontent
        \startframedtext[location=none,frame=off,offset=0pt,width=fit] % width=.45\textwidth
            \starttyping[strip=yes]
                Alternative line 1
                Alternative line 2
                Alternative line 3
            \stoptyping
        \stopframedtext
    \stopcontent
    \startcaption
        B
    \stopcaption
\stopcombination 

\stoptext
```

[image]

When you have more than one combination block in your document you can create extra `typing` and `framedtext` instances and set the settings for both of them only once.

```
\defineframedtext
  [CombinationFrame]
  [location=none,
   frame=off,
   offset=0pt,
   width=fit] % width=.45\textwidth

\definetyping
  [CombinationCode]
  [strip=yes,
   before=\startCombinationFrame,
   after=\stopCombinationFrame]

\starttext 

\startcombination[2*1]
    \startcontent
        \startCombinationCode
        This is sample line 1
        This is sample line 2
        This is sample line 3
        \stopCombinationCode
    \stopcontent
    \startcaption
        A
    \stopcaption
    \startcontent
        \startCombinationCode
        Alternative line 1
        Alternative line 2
        Alternative line 3
        \stopCombinationCode
    \stopcontent
    \startcaption
        B
    \stopcaption
\stopcombination 

\stoptext
```

When you have longer code blocks it can be usefull to put the source code in a buffer and  load the buffer afterwards in the combination.

```
\defineframedtext
  [CombinationFrame]
  [location=none,
   frame=off,
   offset=0pt,
   width=fit] % width=.45\textwidth

\definetyping
  [CombinationCode]
  [strip=yes,
   before=\startCombinationFrame,
   after=\stopCombinationFrame]

\starttext 

\startbuffer[sample-line]
This is sample line 1
This is sample line 2
This is sample line 3
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[alternative-line]
Alternative line 1
Alternative line 2
Alternative line 3
\stopbuffer

\startcombination[2*1]
    \startcontent
        \typeCombinationCodebuffer[sample-line]
    \stopcontent
    \startcaption
        A
    \stopcaption
    \startcontent
        \typeCombinationCodebuffer[alternative-line]
    \stopcontent
    \startcaption
        B
    \stopcaption
\stopcombination 

\stoptext
```

Comment: Using `framedtext` was my first try to answer this question, but I couldn't figure how to avoid those whole width problems. Now I know how…

Comment: My actually usage needs a framed box with background, I eliminated that from the MWE as I tried to get to the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may use paragraphs. Works also with typing.

```
\defineparagraphs [Block] [n=2]
\starttext 
\startBlock
\starttyping
This is sample line 1
This is sample line 2
This is sample line 3
\stoptyping
\Block
\starttyping
Alternative line 1
Alternative line 2
Alternative line 3
\stoptyping
\stopBlock
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2):

Combinations are typeset in horizontal mode, so there will be no linebreaks.  You can use `\framed` to make boxes, where linebreaking is enabled.  I recommend combining that with buffers.

```
\starttext 

\startbuffer[A]
This is sample line 1
This is sample line 2
This is sample line 3
\stopbuffer

\startcombination[2*1]
  {%
    \startframed[frame=off,width=fit,align=right,strut=no]
      \typebuffer[A][before=,after=]
    \stopframed
  }{A}
  {%
    \startframed[frame=off,width=fit,align=right,strut=no]
      \setuptyping[before=,after=]
      \starttyping
Alternative line 1
Alternative line 2
Alternative line 3
      \stoptyping
    \stopframed
  }{B}
\stopcombination

\stoptext
```

[image]